# Reduce по объекту, вытащить нужные свойства

Tags: javascript, объекты, ecmascript-6, map, filter

Есть объект.

```
    var data = {
  "podauschaya_linya_1_kontura_name": {
    "Короткая посадочное": {
      "Значение резьбы": "G 1\"",
      "Диаметр отверстия": 30,
      "Подходящая номенклатура из 1С": {
        "Наименование": "Стоимость сверления отверстия AISI 304 (толщ. 2 мм.) 30",
      },
      "Цена": "36"
    }
  },
  "podauschaya_linya_2_kontura_name": {
    "Короткая посадочное": {
      "Значение резьбы": "G 1\"",
      "Диаметр отверстия": 30,
      "Подходящая номенклатура из 1С": {
        "Наименование": "Стоимость сверления отверстия AISI 304 (толщ. 2 мм.) 30",
      },
      "Цена": "36"
    }
  },
  "obratnaya_linya_2_kontura_name": {
    "Короткая посадочное": {
      "Значение резьбы": "G 1\"",
      "Диаметр отверстия": 30,
      "Подходящая номенклатура из 1С": {
        "Наименование": "Стоимость сверления отверстия AISI 304 (толщ. 2 мм.) 30",
      },
      "Цена": "36"
    }
  },
  "obratnaya_linya_1_kontura_name": {
    "Короткая посадочное": {
      "Значение резьбы": "G 1\"",
      "Диаметр отверстия": 30,
      "Подходящая номенклатура из 1С": {
        "Наименование": "Стоимость сверления отверстия AISI 304 (толщ. 2 мм.) 30",
      },
      "Цена": "36"
    }
  },
  "podauschaya_linya_rezervnogo_kotla_name": {
    "Короткая посадочное": {
      "Значение резьбы": "G ¾\"",
      "Диаметр отверстия": 25,
      "Подходящая номенклатура из 1С": {
        "Наименование": "Стоимость сверления отверстия AISI 304 (толщ. 2 мм.) 25",
      },
      "Цена": "30"
    }
  },
  "obratnaya_linya_rezervnogo_kotla_name": {
    "Короткая посадочное": {
      "Значение резьбы": "G ¾\"",
      "Диаметр отверстия": 25,
      "Подходящая номенклатура из 1С": {
        "Наименование": "Стоимость сверления отверстия AISI 304 (толщ. 2 мм.) 25",
      },
      "Цена": "30"
    }
  },
  "kotlovoi_kontur_select_name": {
    "Короткая посадочное слева_сверху": {
      "Значение резьбы": "G 1\"",
      "Диаметр отверстия": 30,
      "Подходящая номенклатура из 1С": {
        "Наименование": "Стоимость сверления отверстия AISI 304 (толщ. 2 мм.) 30",
      },
      "Цена": "36"
    },
    "Короткая посадочное слева_снизу": {
      "Значение резьбы": "G 1\"",
      "Диаметр отверстия": 30,
      "Подходящая номенклатура из 1С": {
        "Наименование": "Стоимость сверления отверстия AISI 304 (толщ. 2 мм.) 30",
      },
      "Цена": "36"
    }
  }
}
```

Понимаю что должен помочь Reduce, но запутался во вложенности.

```
var getCollectInformation = data => Object.keys(data).reduce( (result, key) =>{ ... }

/* Object.keys(data) даёт доступ к такой вложенности */
[
  "podauschaya_linya_1_kontura_name",
  "podauschaya_linya_2_kontura_name",
  "podauschaya_linya_rezervnogo_kotla_name",
  "obratnaya_linya_rezervnogo_kotla_name"
]
```

Comment: Поправил, изначальный объект немного. Ключ ["Короткая посадочное"] не всегда такой..
Ключи
`"kotlovoi_kontur_select_name": {
    "Короткая посадочное слева_сверху": { }
}`
Будет меняться

Comment: То есть, всегда есть 2 уровня вложенности, а дальше свойства

Comment: Значит ключ `"Короткая посадочное ..."` надо получать динамически: `Object.keys(data[key])[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `/* Object.keys(data) даёт доступ к такой вложенности */`

А дальше идут однотипные объекты, к полям которых можно обращаться по именам.

Также можно воспользоваться методом [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), который сразу возвращает значения объекта, а не только ключи.

Например:

```js
var data = {
  "podauschaya_linya_1_kontura_name": {
    "Короткая посадочное": {
      "Значение резьбы": "G 1\"",
      "Диаметр отверстия": 30,
      "Подходящая номенклатура из 1С": {
        "Наименование": "Стоимость сверления отверстия AISI 304 (толщ. 2 мм.) 30",
      },
      "Цена": "36"
    }
  },
  "podauschaya_linya_2_kontura_name": {
    "Короткая посадочное": {
      "Значение резьбы": "G 1\"",
      "Диаметр отверстия": 30,
      "Подходящая номенклатура из 1С": {
        "Наименование": "Стоимость сверления отверстия AISI 304 (толщ. 2 мм.) 30",
      },
      "Цена": "36"
    }
  },
  "podauschaya_linya_rezervnogo_kotla_name": {
    "Короткая посадочное": {
      "Значение резьбы": "G ¾\"",
      "Диаметр отверстия": 25,
      "Подходящая номенклатура из 1С": {
        "Наименование": "Стоимость сверления отверстия AISI 304 (толщ. 2 мм.) 25",
      },
      "Цена": "30"
    }
  },
  "obratnaya_linya_rezervnogo_kotla_name": {
    "Короткая посадочное": {
      "Значение резьбы": "G ¾\"",
      "Диаметр отверстия": 25,
      "Подходящая номенклатура из 1С": {
        "Наименование": "Стоимость сверления отверстия AISI 304 (толщ. 2 мм.) 25",
      },
      "Цена": "30"
    }
  },
}

var res = Object.values(data).reduce((result, val) => {
  var obj = val["Короткая посадочное"];
  // для случае если имя "Короткая посадочное" может меняться
  // var obj = Object.values(val)[0];
  // либо с помощью `for`
  // var obj;
  // for(var i in val) {
  //   obj = val[i];
  //   break;
  //}
  var key = obj["Подходящая номенклатура из 1С"]["Наименование"];
  if (!result[key]) {
    result[key] = {
      'Количество вхождений в объекте': 1,
      "Значение резьбы": obj["Значение резьбы"],
      'Цена': obj['Цена'],
    };
  } else {
    result[key]['Количество вхождений в объекте'] += 1;
  }
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Ключ ["Короткая посадочное"] не всегда такой.. 
Ключи 
`"kotlovoi_kontur_select_name": { "Короткая посадочное слева_сверху": { } }`
Будет меняться.   
То есть, всегда есть 2 уровня вложенности, а дальше свойства.

в `var obj = val["Короткая посадочное"];` не получить ведь динамический ключ

Comment: @Николай, это стоило в примере данных отобразить :-) но суть не меняется, просто от обращения по имени также берется список значений и из него нулевой элемент

Comment: @Николай, Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = {
  "podauschaya_linya_1_kontura_name": {
    "Короткая посадочное": {
      "Значение резьбы": "G 1\"",
      "Диаметр отверстия": 30,
      "Подходящая номенклатура из 1С": {
        "Наименование": "Стоимость сверления отверстия AISI 304 (толщ. 2 мм.) 30",
      },
      "Цена": "36"
    }
  },
  "podauschaya_linya_2_kontura_name": {
    "Короткая посадочное": {
      "Значение резьбы": "G 1\"",
      "Диаметр отверстия": 30,
      "Подходящая номенклатура из 1С": {
        "Наименование": "Стоимость сверления отверстия AISI 304 (толщ. 2 мм.) 30",
      },
      "Цена": "36"
    }
  },
  "podauschaya_linya_rezervnogo_kotla_name": {
    "Короткая посадочное": {
      "Значение резьбы": "G ¾\"",
      "Диаметр отверстия": 25,
      "Подходящая номенклатура из 1С": {
        "Наименование": "Стоимость сверления отверстия AISI 304 (толщ. 2 мм.) 25",
      },
      "Цена": "30"
    }
  },
  "obratnaya_linya_rezervnogo_kotla_name": {
    "Короткая посадочное": {
      "Значение резьбы": "G ¾\"",
      "Диаметр отверстия": 25,
      "Подходящая номенклатура из 1С": {
        "Наименование": "Стоимость сверления отверстия AISI 304 (толщ. 2 мм.) 25",
      },
      "Цена": "30"
    }
  },
};
var data1 = {};
for (var key in data) {
  var subkey = Object.keys(data[key])[0];
  var key1 = data[key][subkey]["Подходящая номенклатура из 1С"]["Наименование"];
  if (data1[key1]) {
    data1[key1]["Количество вхождений в объекте"] += 1;
  } else {
    data1[key1] = {
      "Количество вхождений в объекте": 1,
      "Значение резьбы": data[key][subkey]["Значение резьбы"],
      "Цена": data[key][subkey]["Цена"] 
    };
  }
}
console.log(data1);
```